# jsPDF server side (node.js) usage using node-jspdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, jspdf

I am actually trying to include jspdf in server side and then use it for simple pdf generation(simply the text "Hello world!")(Go to the url- get the pdf localhost:8080). Now the first problem I face is

- How to include it / What to do to use jsPDF in node?
- While trying to install it using `npm install node-jspdf` then it gives following error-

---

```
> G:\test\myproj>npm install node-jspdf
 node-jspdf@0.0.3 install G:\test\myproj\node_modules\node-jspdf
 sh install.sh
```

> ```
> 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
> npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
> \\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-jspdf"
> npm ERR! node v0.12.4
> npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! node-jspdf@0.0.3 install: `sh install.sh`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-jspdf@0.0.3 install script 'sh install.sh'.
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-jspdf package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     sh install.sh
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-jspdf
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     G:\test\myproj\npm-debug.log
> ```

Can anybody help me on how to include it in node? And give a 4-5 line demo.

Comment: @Eric.: Go to github repo and download

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE:** Jspdf now support nodejs so should be able to import jspdf without having to add the browser globals as outlined in this answer.

You can actually use jspdf directly (`npm install jspdf` instead of `npm install node-jspdf`). Jspdf is currently (v1.3.2) not built with node support in mind, but you can mock the globals like below and get it to work that way. This is a basic example and all features of jspdf will not be available.

```
global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => {return {}} }};
global.navigator = {};
global.html2pdf = {};
global.btoa = () => {};

var fs = require('fs');
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text("Hello", 10, 10);
var data = doc.output();

fs.writeFileSync('./document.pdf', data, 'binary');

delete global.window;
delete global.html2pdf;
delete global.navigator;
delete global.btoa;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I just had to change let for var. Thank you very much this will save me a ton of time.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered the problem was my node version.  When you did this example, did you try to generate it with an image ? would be nice to know, thats the last part i'm stuck with.

Comment: You mean using doc.addImage? Nope, have not tried that.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering so fast :O, yes meant just that, I haven´t been able to work around it and worry i'll have to port all my code to pdfkit.

Comment: I tried this. But as a pity this approach does not give Umlauts. I tried with doc.text("Hello öäüßÖÄÜ©€®†", 10, 10); but  the result was "Hello Ã¶Ã¤Ã1⁄4ÃŸÃ–Ã„ÃœÂ©Â€Â®Â†"

Comment: I struggle with this for hours. It is a matter of encoding as PDF does not handle utf-8 characters. I desparately search how I can tweak "data" to make it work properly. I am running node on MacOs. I would even be able to manipulate the text before I hand it over to jspdf.

Comment: Jspdf does not support utf8 right now and don't think it will get utf8 support any time soon unfortunately.

Comment: When i use  it in the browser, get the PDF as Blob and save it to dropbox with dropbox  API, I get the correct characters. When i use output('datauri') and open  a browser window, I also get the correct characters. So there should be a way to achieve the same server Side.

Comment: I managed to use encoding to fix the issue at least for latin-1 characters. Posted the code in another answer. Thanks

Comment: I still get `window is not defined` issue on nodejs inside `jspdf.min.js:8:1` how did you fix that? It does not seem to take the globals

Comment: I ended up using `pdfmake` instead of jspdf. Since it works client and server side out of the box.

Comment: This did not work for me I got an error. "ReferenceError: html2pdf is not defined
    at /home/davidw/Projects/rnd/jspdf-test/node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js:202:16291
    at /home/davidw/Projects/rnd/jspdf-test/node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js:1:124"

Comment: Added html2pdf to globals above

Comment: Hi, I tried the above, but receive the following error on the line var doc = new jsPDF():
TypeError: jsPDF is not a constructor

Answer (score 3):

In extension to the answer provided by Simon Bengtsson:

I managed to handle even latin-1 characters by sending the output of jsPdf to encoding:

```
global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => {return {}} }};
global.navigator = {};
global.btoa = () => {};

var fs = require('fs');
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');
var encoding = require('encoding')
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text("HelloäöüßÄÖÜ©µ®", 10, 10);
var data = doc.output()
var buffer = encoding.convert(data, "Latin_1") 

fs.writeFileSync('./document.pdf', buffer);

delete global.window;
delete global.navigator;
delete global.btoa;
```

Comment: Saving as binary seems to be a better way to fix the encoding issues, i.e. `fs.writeFileSync(filePath, doc.output(), 'binary');` - works well for me.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: Added 'binary' to my answer above! Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I am able to install [node-jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jspdf) in Windows.

1. As suggested download [jspdf-master.zip](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/archive/master.zip) and extract it.
2. Now use the command:

   ```
   npm install <location on jspdf-master extract>
   ```

After that you can use `npm list` to see the installation success.

Comment: Where can I download the jspdf-master.zip from?

Answer (score 0):

`Node-jspdf` mainly uses library [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) as the core library to render PDF file

but `node-jspdf` can only be installed on `*unix` system therefore you can download and install `jsPDF` manually by following steps in [this file](https://github.com/calvinfroedge/node-jspdf/blob/master/install.sh)

I think you only need to install `jsPDF` to work with PDF file.

Comment: .: Sorry! I can't get it. In windows how am i gonna install it? Please be clear

Comment: .: Can you  plz give a sample server demo with it?

Answer (score -3):

Download your jspdf folder from parallax jspdf. After installing jspdf ( "npm install jspdf" )  you get the jspdf folder inside node-modules. Go inside it and replace the jspdf.min.js by the jspdf.amd.min.js present in the /dist folder inside the jspdf downloaded from parallax

Comment: Changing something in the node modules is always a bad idea and should be avoided at any cost.