# node-jspdf pdf generation node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, jspdf

I am actually trying to include node-jspdf in node.js application.

Steps performed

- npm install node-jspdf --save
- cd node_modules/node-jspdf/
- npm install

ge-pdf.js content

```
var jspdf = require('node-jspdf');
```

execute file
node ge-pdf.js

throws below error

```
Error: Cannot find module './vendor/jsPDF/jspdf.plugin.addhtml.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
```

updated node_modules/node-jspdf/index.js file

```
plugins.map(function(plugin){
    require(path+'jspdf.plugin.'+plugin+'.js');
});
```

to

```
plugins.map(function(plugin){
    require(path+'plugins/'+plugin+'.js');
});
```

after this change, when i execute the file. 
node ge-pdf.js

below error is thrown

```
node_modules/node-jspdf/vendor/jsPDF/plugins/addhtml.js:116
})(jsPDF.API);
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'API' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/antho/node_pdf/node_modules/node-jspdf/vendor/jsPDF/plugins/addhtml.js:116:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /home/antho/node_pdf/node_modules/node-jspdf/index.js:7:5
```

Comment: I am noticing that you wrote `var jspdf = require('node-jspdf');` but the variable you used in the bottom is `jsPDF'. Might just be a uppercase/lowercase syntax error.

Comment: case is  correct. module name is also correct, after looking at the package.json file.   https://github.com/calvinfroedge/node-jspdf/tree/master.    Error is thrown at the first line require('node-jspdf').

Comment: Note that you can use jspdf with node directly with some small hacks. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41898470/827047

Answer (score 2):

This is logged as an [issue](https://github.com/calvinfroedge/node-jspdf/issues/3) on node-jspdf's Github.

> Node-jspdf brings in the 'master' version of jspdf. The version of
>   node-jspdf that is currently in the npm repository (0.0.3) is not
>   compatible with the master version of jspdf.
>
> If you do a 'npm install
>   https://github.com/calvinfroedge/node-jspdf.git', that will get you a
>   newer copy of node-jspdf that is compatible with the master version of
>   jspdf.