# jspdf error in node JS + windows 10

Tags: javascript, printing, jspdf

everyone,

I just found that amazing library in npmjs.com, called jspdf.

So, in a windows 10 machine + chrome 57, i tried it in runkit+NPM, but the console throw an error that said that window is not definded, which make sense, because the window context in js is replaced by global, in Node. after installing the package and test it on my local machine, the same error appears. I cannot find other users with the same issue in stackoverflow or anywhere. Am I missing something about the package installation or configurations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Care to share some code ?

Comment: Also, check this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694428/jspdf-server-side-node-js-usage-using-node-jspdf), might help you.

Comment: not problem! the code is very simple, copied from the github repo. The problem occurs when nodejs "call" the library and detects that window object. here all the code from the js file:

`const pdfPrinter = require("jspdf");
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10)
doc.save('a4.pdf')`

Comment: I´ll try to install the zip. Thank you! But even in runkit+npm (a browser sandbox) this issue is pointed.

Comment: Same issue, installing from servers or from zip file :(