# jspdf module crashing every time with ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, jspdf

I am working on a small project that works with generating pdf's in node and express, and been trying to use the `jspdf npm` module but somehow whenever I install that package and require it its crashing my sever. Here in how I am requiring in my `server.js` file:

```
var jsPDF = require('jspdf')
```

And this is the response that it is giving me when l try to run my server:

> (window.AcroForm=function(t){var n=window.AcroForm;n.scale=function(t)        {return t*(r.internal.scaleFactor/1)},n.antiScale=function(t){return  1/r.internal.scaleFactor*t};var r={fields:[],xForms:[],acroFormDictionaryRoot:null,printedOut:!1,internal:null};e.API.acroformPlugin=r;var i=function(){for(var t in this.acroformPlugin.acroFormDictionaryRoot.Fields){var e=this.acroformPlugin.acroFormDictionaryRoot.Fields[t];e.hasAnnotation&&a.call(this,e)}},o=function(){if(this.acroformPlugin.acroFormDictionaryRoot)throw new Error("Exception while creating AcroformDictionary");this.acroformPlugin.acroFormDictionaryRoot=new n.AcroFormDictionary,this.acroformPlugin.internal=this.internal,this.acroformPlugin.acroFormDictionaryRoot._eventID=this.internal.events.subscribe("postPutResources",l),this.internal.events.subscribe("buildDocument",i),this.internal.events.subscribe("putCatalog",c),this.internal.events.subscribe("pos
>
> ```
> ReferenceError: window is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library is for the client side (web browser) which is why it's expecting a window variable to be present. Luckily someone has already answered how to make this work server side [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41898470/5834359). Taken from that answer:

```js
global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => {return {}} }};
global.navigator = {};
global.btoa = () => {};

var fs = require('fs');
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text("Hello", 10, 10);
var data = doc.output();

fs.writeFileSync('./document.pdf', data);

delete global.window;
delete global.navigator;
delete global.btoa;
```