# How do I return a generated PDF from an ExpressJS application?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pdf, mime-types

I'm trying to get an Express application to return a generated PDF. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41898470/35961), I'm trying to use the `jsPDF` library, with some fake globals. Also adding to the confusion is that the data is being fetched from a Postgres source.

I've never used `.blob()` before, and I suspect that that's the reason I'm not getting a response. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const SQL = require('sql-template-strings')
const { Client } = require('pg')
const dbConfig = require('../db')

const FormRouter = express.Router()

function saveFormAsPDF(form) {
  global.window = {
    document: {
      createElementNS: () => {
        return {}
      },
    },
  }
  global.navigator = {}
  global.html2pdf = {}
  global.btoa = () => {}

  const jsPDF = require('jspdf') // wrapped by the fake globals
  const doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'landscape',
    format: 'a4',
  })

  doc.setFontSize(24)
  doc.text('Form: ' + (form.identifier || 'Awaiting Retrieval'), 20, 20)
  var data = doc.output()

  delete global.window
  delete global.html2pdf
  delete global.navigator
  delete global.btoa
  return data
}

const getFormAsPDFByIdRoute = (req, res) => {
  const client = new Client(dbConfig)
  client.connect()
  return client
    .query(SQL`SELECT * FROM forms WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`)
    .then(result => {
      res
        .status(result.rowCount === 0 ? 404 : 200)
        .set({ 'content-type': 'application/pdf' })
        .blob( saveFormAsPDF(result.rows[0]) )
    })
    .then(() => client.end())
}

FormRouter.route('/id/:id').get(getFormsByIdRoute)

FormRouter.route('/pdf/:id').get(getFormAsPDFByIdRoute)

exports.FormRouter = FormRouter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I finally managed this. Here's the code:

```js
const express = require('express')

const getPDF = (req, res) => {
  // This is a hack
  // We are over-riding the global objects in node, so that jsPDF thinks
  // that it is running inside a browser.
  // NB: The global assignments, and jspdf require statement must therefore
  // be in the following order for this to work.
  global.window = {
    document: {
      createElementNS: () => {
        return {}
      },
    },
  }
  global.navigator = {}
  global.btoa = () => {}
  global.html2pdf = {}
  const jsPDF = require('jspdf')

  const doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: orientation,
    format: 'a4',
  })

  // PDF building code goes here, e.g.

  doc.setFontSize(40)
  doc.text(35, 25, 'jsPDF *can* be made to work with Express!')

  const myPDF = doc.output()

  res.status(200)
    .set({ 'content-type': 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8' })
    .send(myPDF)
}

PDFRouter.route('/pdf').get(getPDF)

exports.PDFRouter = PDFRouter
```

There was one additional gotcha. In my building code I was using named colours, e.g.

```js
doc.setTextColor('blue')
doc.text('This is in blue', 50, 50)
doc.setTextColor('black')
doc.text('This is in black', 50, 75)
```

This worked fine if run in a browser, but for node 'RGBCcolor' could not be found, and the require hack above didn't seem to cut it. A quick hack was just to use three params for R G B, vai some constant array spreading e.g.

```js
// define some colours
const black = [0, 0, 0]
const blue = [0, 0, 150]

doc.setTextColor(...blue)
doc.text('This is in blue', 50, 50)
doc.setTextColor(...black)
doc.text('This is in black', 50, 75)
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I noticed in your code was that you're not waiting for the `client.connect()` call to resolve. If you don't pass a callback to the function a promise is returned which you should await.

Regarding generating pdfs:

I had a similar requirement for generating pdfs from html some time ago and I ended up using the `html-pdf` [library](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf).

Using this library you would simply create a conversion stream and pipe it into the response. Something like this (still needs proper error handling):

```
const html2pdf = require('html-pdf');

const getFormAsPDFByIdRoute = async(req, res) => {
    const client = new Client(dbConfig);
    await client.connect();
    const result = await client.query(SQL `SELECT * FROM forms WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`);
    if (!result.rowCount) {
        return res.status(404).end();
    }
    const stream = await createHtlm2PdfStream(result.rows[0]);
    res.contentType('application/pdf');
    stream.pipe(res);
}

function createHtlm2PdfStream(html) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        html2pdf.create(html).toStream((err, stream) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(stream);
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: as I was assuming the pdf was to be generated from html, but instead the pdf should be built manually using pdfkit seems to be a valid choice:

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

const getFormAsPDFByIdRoute = async(req, res) => {
    const client = new Client(dbConfig);
    await client.connect();
    const result = await client.query(SQL `SELECT * FROM forms WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`);
    if (!result.rowCount) {
        return res.status(404).end();
    }
    const doc = new PDFDocument();
    res.contentType('application/pdf');
    doc.pipe(res);
    // render some text (you can use .font(...) to alter the font style)
    const formContent = result.rows[0];
    doc.text(`Some text with the form id ${formContent.identifier}`, 100, 100);
    doc.end();
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm not doing it in the front end, I'm building the PDF manully and not using HTML.

Comment: Oh, ok - I misunderstood that part, sorry. I'd recommend using pdfkit in that case (https://pdfkit.org/). Here's a tutorial that might help you get started: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/generate-invoices-pdfkit-node/

Comment: I already have quite a lot invested in the coding for generating the PDF using jspdf. I'm reluctant to switch to what looks a lot like an SVG-based model. I'm sure it has it's pluses, and the text flow looks good. I'll have a think.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Btw: did you see my comment on awaiting the `client.connect()` call? Maybe this causes the issue that you don't get any response.